# How can I draw an ellipse as a path in svg?

Tags: svg

I have to draw the solar system in a svg file, so I have to draw an ellipse in a svg as a path.

Someone could help me?

```
<!--Venus-->
    <path id="venere" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"
        d="
        M 650, 300
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        "
    />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="green">      
        <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#venere"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
```

This create a circle, but I need an ellipse

Comment: Why can't you draw the ellipse as an [ellipse](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/ellipse)?

Comment: i can't draw the ellipse as an ellipse because I have to move over a circle.

Comment: I have to draw the solar system, so I have to move the planet (circle) over the ellipse (path)

Comment: if i draw an ellipse i can't move the circle over the ellipse. If I make an ellipse with path i can move it

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a circle because the rx and ry values of the elliptical arc are both 75 (they are the two values immediately after the a command). If they were different you'd get an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with simplified code, where the ellipse is draw in a single stroke, as opposed to being draw as two halves.

```
<path id="venere" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"
    d="M 650, 150 a 75,150 0 1,0 1,0"/>
```

Comment: There is one small pixel missing

Comment: Could you explain what are 650, 150, 75 etc. please?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#arcs

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous solution, if you add *closepath* command `z` to the end, you will get rid of missing pixel point. So it should be:

```
<path id="venere" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"
    d="M 650, 150 a 75,150 0 1,0 1,0 z"/>
```